# Spring 4 gs-rest-service gives Not acceptable 406 error

Tags: spring, rest

I'm trying to run the sample gs-rest-service-complete (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) and get:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Jun 12 15:03:05 SGT 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

I've not made any modification on the code.

Here's the Greeting.java file

```
package hello;

public class Greeting {

private final long id;
private final String content;

public Greeting(long id, String content) {
    this.id = id;
    this.content = content;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}
}
```

The Controller class:

```
package hello;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping(value="/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        String.format(template, name));
}
}
```

I use the Application class to launch through spring boot:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

And here is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

I use Spring Tool Suite and imported the project directly from server. I run the project using spring boot.

Any specific configuration I've forgotten ?

---

I finally got this example to work by adding 2 dependencies in the pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This is a strange behavior as those dependencies are included in spring-boot:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

It was working for jackson-databind but not for the other two.

If anyone can explain this, please let me know.

Comment: Without looking into anything, the first thing I would try is to set the `Accept` header on your request to `application/json`

Comment: I've tried to add this but same result, I get a status 406. I just install the environment with new STS and import directly from spring example, maybe I miss some preriquisites

Comment: You should add the solution to provided as answer to the question. It'll be easier for the folks who face the same issue to locate the answer.